# Is it possible to make an arbitrary lake bottom generator?

Tags: sensors, c++, system-design

I'm trying to generate an arbitrary lake bottom sonar returns using my Arduino.

I would like to seed a function with a "depth." This would be the starting depth. I would then like to randomize a set of parameters each time the function is called. **The output would look something like a time-truncated sine wave. The parameters would include:**

1. Randomized Amplitude of waveform (which wouldn't vary too much)
2. Randomized Period (or frequency) of waveform (also wouldn't vary too much)
3. Randomized exit point. Say the period is 10 seconds but function ends at 7 seconds. This would allow for a changing in depth over time even if random.
4. If possible, I would like to low pass filter the output to smooth any hard transitions.

Any suggestions on where to get started?

Comment: Not sure this is even related to Arduino. electronics.stackexchange.com might be better place.

Answer (score 1):

A common method of generating realistic-ish 3d terrain is as follows:

Start with a square (as seen top-down), described by the lengths of it's side (all the same), and the height of each of the corners.

Divide each edge in half; for example, add a new point halfway between the north-west point and the north-east point; it's altitude will be the average of the altitude of the two existing points, plus or minus a random number.

Now add a point in the center of the existing square; it's altitude being the average of the north, east, west and south points you've just created, plus or minus a random number.

You now have 4 smaller squares. Repeat this process on the four smaller squares, then the smaller squares within that, and so forth.

You might want to manually do the first few points, tweaking it to get the shape you want, then leave the details to the algorithm. Your random number for the adjustments of the "middle point" heights should be proportionate to the length of the sides; for example, the random altitude adjustment might be a random number up to X% the length; then subtract half of X% of the length. Adjusting X% will give you an area that is more or less "pointy".